# C++: Pointer not initialized but pointing to a variable

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int main() 
{
    int b = 10;
    int* bPointer;
    *bPointer = b;
    cout << *bPointer << endl;
    cout << bPointer;
}
```

first cout prints 10, second prints 0. How can a pointer pointing to ***0*** store some value?

Comment: The answer is that C++ is like a gun, that you can use to shoot yourself in a foot with. And hit all ten toes, on both feet. With one shot.

Comment: Why the downvote by the way?

Comment: When I run this code, I get a segmentation fault. Such is the way with undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Chittolina The code has a simple and obvious bug. If you fix the bug, the mystery goes away. So what's the question? "Why does code with a bug do weird things?" Because that's what bugs do. Fix them.

Comment: try "int *bPointer = 0" and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other comments and answers have already noted, using an uninitialized pointer yields undefined behavior—so you really just shouldn't do that. However, you seem to understand that, but you're still curious about why you see the behavior you're observing...

Since `bPointer` is not declared `volatile`, the compiler can assume that `*bPointer` cannot change during this function scope.

Basically, the compiler sees this assignment

```
*bPointer = b;
```

and then optimizes this line

```
cout << *bPointer << endl;
```

into something like this

```
cout << 10 << endl;
```

which it can assume is equivalent.

The compiler might even be able to deduce that the program ends at this point, and thus skips the assignment to `*bPointer` altogether; however, that seems a bit more farfetched to me.

All of the platform and compiler combinations I tried yielded an error, so I wasn't able to confirm my explanation—but if you're really observing this behavior, that's my educated guess about what happened.

### Update

I was able to reproduce the behavior with g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 when compiling with the `-O1` flag. Here's the relevant assembly<sup>1</sup>:

```
main:
.LFB975:
        .cfi_startproc
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        ; Next 3 lines print "10" (via cout)
        movl    $10, %esi
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        ; Next 2 lines print the `endl` (via cout)
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
        ; Next 3 lines print "0" (via cout)
        movl    $0, %esi
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<void const*>(void const*)
        movl    $0, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
```

As you can see, the compiler completely got rid of both variables (i.e., neither `b` nor `bPointer` has any corresponding memory location on the stack), and instead just assumes constant values (`10` and `0`), which are then printed.

Again, since using an uninitialized pointer results in *undefined* behavior, the compiler is free to do whatever it wants... I think this particular behavior is a bit strange, but it's still "valid" since your pointer is uninitialized.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you're interested, the assembly was generated like this: `g++ -O1 test.cpp -S -o /dev/stdout | c++filt`

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour (usage of uninitialized pointer) **do not do such things** it often causes **access violation exeption** and many other bad things.

Theoreticaly you can write to any place of virtual memory addresses, and retrive values you writed from it, but modern compillers and OS disallowed doing such things, bacause of potentialy error prone situations.

Many compilers cause **access violation exeption**, or **segmentation fault** in this cases, your compiller just pass it away. This may cause many problems with your programs in future.

Comment: Ok. But what's exactly happening there? I mean, how can a uninitialized pointer point to a value if his point address is '0'?

Comment: Undefined behavior is happening. We can't define it any better because it is, by definition, undefined.

Comment: @Chittolina: You just write 10 to virtual memory address with 0 offset. I wonder why compiller do not bit your hands doing such things?

Comment: Step through with a debugger while looking at the disassembly if you want to know exactly what's happening for this instance of undefined behavior. In some cases it's interesting to know what the undefined behavior is. Just be sure to realize that the behavior can change for any reason at all. In this case, I'm not sure how interesting this particular case is.

Comment: If `bPointer` is 0 (which is not guaranteed in this code), writing to address 0 should be causing a runtime error, as most systems reserve address 0 for exactly that purpose.  If course, this is not guaranteed, either.

Comment: I know I should not do that. But I was just wondering why was that happening... Still don't know why the downvote.

Comment: @Chittolina: What kind of compiler you have used?

Comment: Well, you didnt debug on your own and you haven't really shown what you did to answer your question. One of the downvote reasons is "This question shows no research effort".

Comment: @Chittolina The code has a bug. Bugs make code do things you don't expect. You fix the bug, and the problem goes away. Explaining exactly why it caused a particular result requires a detailed investigation of the specifics of the platform, which nobody can do because they don't know your platform, compiler options, and so on. Just fix the bug.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz He's not here to look into why he should fix the bug so much as understand why the bug behaves the way it does. Telling him to fix the bug and ignore the original question isn't helpful. Telling him that it depends on those things you mentioned is though.

Comment: @TankorSmash Honestly, for someone who doesn't really understand what UB is, as it seems is the case here, analyzing why the bug behaves the way it does is more likely to do damage to understanding rather than facilitate it. It takes deep understanding to figure out how UB manifests into particular results and it's actually harmful to delve into it too early. (It tends to lead people to expect predictable or understandable behavior.)

Comment: We're not writing answers only for the asker though, it would be nice for everyone to have a deep understanding of why this behaviour works the way it does.

Answer (score 1):

As many others have said already, your code has **undefined behavior**. It can crash, it can work, it can work for a while and then stop, anything is possible.

---

As you probably know, local variables are stored on a stack. (Or in a register, if optimized, but that's not too relevant here.) In any case, an uninitialized local POD (plain old data) variable is **not guaranteed to contain `0` or `NULL`** or `false` or some other "default" value. It will be set to any garbage which happened to be at the same stack address before.

---

When I compile your program on my local machine for 32 bits, for example, I get output like this:

```
10
004EAF18
```

The latter is apparently some address where a 4-byte `int` value can be written and nothing fatal happens, probably somewhere on the stack or on the heap. But that's just luck, it could point to a read-only segment and fail during the write, or the program could crash later because it could overwrite e.g. `argv` list and then try to use it or whatever.

In any case, this is the reason most people would expect it to not crash and why it does not crash for me - that `bPointer` is set to some wrong but usable address and not really `NULL`, because the zero address is reserved in virtually every OS and process virtual memory setup.

---

But indeed, when I try the same code of yours on e.g. [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/), the output is the weird one you see:

```
10
0
```

And still, it does not crash! What's the catch?

It's the **optimization**, as DaoWen pointed out in their answer.

If you go to [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) and use the defaults, i.e. without optimizations, the output is this assembler code:

```
; b = 10
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 10

; *bPointer = b
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx

; cout << *bPointer
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     esi, eax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)

; cout << endl
    mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))

; cout << bPointer
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(void const*)
```

But if you add even the basic optimization, `-O1` in the "compiler options" on the top right, it's all optimized away:

```
; cout << 10
    mov     esi, 10
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)

; cout << endl
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)

; cout << 0
    mov     esi, 0
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<void const*>(void const*)
```

So that explains it. The last piece of the puzzle is that for some reason, the compiler (GCC here) takes uninitialized pointers as `0` during optimization.

Probably because `0` is as good as any value there, it's undefined behavior. Fix the bug!

Answer (score 0):

Having read through some of the comments and answers on here, one thing that strikes me is how many people seem to be assuming that the 0 said to be printed in the original question is actually the address that the pointer is pointing to. In the code shown:

```
cout << *bPointer << endl;
```

bPointer is being dereferenced. Therefore, the 0 being observed is NOT the address itself, but (supposedly, and subject to previous points about optimisations and undefined behaviour) the number stored AT the address pointed to by bPointer. The question we SHOULD be asking, is why this number is not 10, after the number 10 has been explicitly written there by:

```
*bPointer = b;
```

It can only be assumed that either the UNKNOWN memory address in question cannot be written to, or that the compiler is not doing what you would expect, for reasons already suggested by others.

Comment: You are mistaken, there are two output statements in the code and the OP wrote "first cout [`cout << *bPointer`] prints 10, second [`cout << bPointer`] prints 0".

Comment: @Yirkha Assuming the code in the question has not been edited since I posted this answer, I must have misread the code. In which case, I apologise.

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to let you know :)

Comment: @Yirkha Yes, thanks for that. :) All I know is I remember it as `cout << b` and then `cout << *bPointer`, and that’s what I thought it was when I posted that answer, so I don’t know what happened there.